# Get the actual recipient of an exchange email

Tags: vbscript, outlook, exchange-server-2010

I have the following bit of code:

```
For each Item in ofChosenFolder.Items
    msgbox Item.Subject
    for each recip in Item.Recipients
        msgbox "sent to " & recip.address
        msgbox "sent to " & recip.addressEntry
    next
next
```

I have some emails addressed to me awalker@example.com and other addressed to projects@example.com.

All are received by my exchange mailbox.

Using the above code I always get my Exchange /O=EXAMPLE/OU=EXCHANGE.../CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=A Walker, etc and my Exchange name "A Walker". This is because Exchange resolves the emails against the Global Address Book.

Is there any way to stop it resolving the email addresses and identify the actual smtp address the email was sent to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a perfectly valid EX type address. To get the SMTP address

1. Check the `AddressEntry.Type` property. If it is "SMTP", just use the `AddressEntry.Address` property.
2. If it is "EX", use `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress`

---

The answer is to get `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS`.

To do this in VBS:

```
For Each Item in myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).items
    PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"  
    Set oPA = Item.PropertyAccessor
    Header = oPA.GetProperty(PropName)
    'parse the "To" line out of your header to get the email address
Next
```

Comment: Both addresses are for the same Exchange mailbox. Hence the address type for both addresses is EX. Step 2 then becomes redundant as the PrimarySmtpAddress for the mailbox is awalker@example.com, which it picks up for both that and email sent to projects@example.com too.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean - do you mean both SMTP addresses are proxy addresses for the same mailbox? Have you looked at the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS property?

Comment: Sorry, I have only just returned to looking at this issue.
I have printed the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS and they show my projects@example.com as the "received from" (not the "to" like in emails sent to awalker@example.com).
However it also shows EX for my AddressEntry.Type 
and awalker@example.com for my AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress!!

Comment: So what does To header how in PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS?

Comment: It doesn't. There is no "To" header!
However, I have got around my problem by scanning for projects@example.com anywhere in the header.
It's not ideal but will suffice in this instance.

Comment: So how the message was sent to that mailbox? Can you post the full PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS property? You can see it in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button).

Comment: Ahh, It wasn't displaying ALL the header when I checked the value in my debugger. there is a "To" line in there with the correct value. That's great, I can parse that. Thanks for your help.